# A book about a girl who experience murders in her dreams

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it a few years ago, and I really just can't remember the title of the book. I probably read it on Google Play books/Play Store for free. It's about a girl who experiences real murders in her dreams, but she's not a spectator or anything; she sees it through the victim, and she feels their pain. I think it also manifests to her reality because I vividly remember reading about how every time she (the victim) gets hurt in the dream, her body that is sleeping gets hurt too and she even wakes up on her bed sheets full of blood. The main guy is a police officer. That's literally all I can remember, and I'm sorry if I didn't explain very well. English isn't my first language.

Comment: Is the girl using her memories of the dreams to locate the bodies for the FBI?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but since no other answers have been posted I'm going to suggest [Killing Dreams](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58978907-killing-dreams) by Donnette Smith. It was published in 2021 so that's two years ago and it is [on the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Donnette_Smith_Killing_Dreams?id=k_c_EAAAQBAJ) though it isn't free.

[image: Killing Dreams]

The protagonist *Jenna Langley* experiences the murders in her dreams, and she experiences them as if she was the person being murdered and feels the murder victim's pain. However I don't think she wakes up with the injuries of the victim. There is a limited preview available [on Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Killing_Dreams/k_c_EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), and searching this for *sheets* and *blood* doesn't find anything like your memory of the protagonist waking to find the sheets soaked in blood.

The other main protagonist is a homicide detective as you recall. His name is *Cole Rainwater* and he and Jenna were lovers but broke up when it was revealed that Cole's father was a serial killer.